# MatLab symbolic output calculations

Tags: matlab

I have the following matlab code which calucaltes the Hessian of a non linear function using the symbolic toolbox

```
clc;
syms x1 x2 x3;
f = 4*x1^4*x2^(5/3)*x3^(-5);
h(x1,x2,x3) = hessian(f)
h(1,1,1)
eig(h(1,1,1))
```

I am trying to find the Eigen values of the Hessian so that I can prove that it is not a positive semi definite matrix.

My issue is the way the output is formatted. I am getting all my calculations as fractions and not decimals? Can i change it anywhere to output decimals instead of fractions?
Output
http://pastebin.com/11HHnmRn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look e.g. at the result `h(1,1,1)`:

```
ans =
    [   48,   80/3,    -80]
    [ 80/3,   40/9, -100/3]
    [  -80, -100/3,    120]
```

You can not simplify `80/3`  any further without losing precision. This is why the MATLAB Symbolic Toolbox doesn't do anything further with it. The same happens e.g. with `sqrt(2)`, which can't be simplified anymore either.

If you *chose* to discard this precision, in order get decimals, and be able to do further calculations with MATLAB, you can simply convert the expression to [`double`](http://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/double.html) precision:

```
double(h(1,1,1))

ans =
   48.0000   26.6667  -80.0000
   26.6667    4.4444  -33.3333
  -80.0000  -33.3333  120.0000
```

Comment: ... or use [`vpa`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) for an arbitrary level of precision.